# Shifting picture inside tikz using \includegraphicx

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to vertically shift the pictures inside the brackets so that they are aligned along "Cone" in the following diagram. This diagram is done inside TikZ environment. I do not understand what to change inside the `\includegraphicx` to achieve that:
Here is a sample code:

```
\node [xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm] (X) at (0,0){$ \Bigg[\includegraphics[scale=0.5, width=0.9cm, height=0.9cm]{PKink.pdf}  \Bigg]
```

[image]

Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please, always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with ˙\documentclass`and ending by`\end{document}`.
- Try to insert image into math expression and accordingly set its baseline:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\[
\mathit{Cone} \Bigg[
    \tikz[baseline=-3pt]\node {\includegraphics[width=0.9cm]{example-image-duck}};  %{PKink.pdf}  
\Bigg]_{(C_0,\delta_0)}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I could not have constructed such a code in thousand years. Really appreciate your time to answer it.

Comment: @Monkey.D.Luffy, oh, by experiences you will learn :-). If you like answer so much, than you can upvote and  accept answer (by clicking on the up-triangle and check mark at top left side of anser) :-)